# How do I calculate how many times were digits used in a chain of integers?

Tags: c++, int, digits

It seems like an easy task but for some reason my code just doesn't work.
I've tried shifting the parts around to see what changes, fixed the wrongly used variables, but the environment still crashes every time when I try to build and run the program.

Here's my code:

```
int n, a, dgt, I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX;
    cout << "Enter an integer: \n";
    cin >> n;
    a = n;
    while (a > 0)                    // I use this cycle to seperate every number of the chain
    {
        while (n > 0)                // I use this cycle to analyze every number of the chain
        {
            dgt = n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
            if (dgt == 1) I ++;
            if (dgt == 2) II++;
            if (dgt == 3) III ++;
            if (dgt == 4) IV ++;
            if (dgt == 5) V ++;
            if (dgt == 6) VI ++;
            if (dgt == 7) VII ++;
            if (dgt == 8) VIII ++;
            if (dgt == 9) IX ++;
        }

        a--;
    }
```

I will be thankful for any advice that you could give me :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: `int n, a, dgt, I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX;` are any of these initialized ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and describe in more detail in which way your code fails.

Comment: BTW: As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, for questions like yours, you need to extract and provide a [mcve], so that everyone can just grab your code and run it to reproduce your problem.

Comment: You don't need the outer loop.

Comment: It seems that the concept of arrays could greatly simplify your programmer life.

Comment: Did you forget `if (dgt == 0) O ++;` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a more ore less standard approach for calculating the frequency of an item.

Use a `std::map` with the key equal to the item and a counter. For example:

```
std::map<SomeType, size_t> frequencyOfSomeType;
```

If you use the index operator [] of the `std::map`, 2 things may happen.

1. If the key already exists, it will return a reference to the entry
2. If the key does not exist, it will be created and a reference to the entry will be returned.

If you then apply the ++ post increment operator, the counter for the new or existing key will be increased. You will see such kind of solutions all over the place.

A further necessary step is, to convert a value to a string, or, even better, read the number as a stringin the first place. Then we iterate over the characters (digits) in the string and count them.

At the end, we show the result.

Please the a simple example code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    // Ask user to enter an integer
    std::cout << "Enter an unsigned integer: ";
    if (unsigned long long value{}; std::cin >> value) {

        // convert integer to std::string
        std::string valueString{std::to_string(value)};

        // Now count the digits
        std::map<char,size_t> digitCounter{};
        for (const char& d : valueString) digitCounter[d]++;

        // Ouput result:
        for (const auto& [digit, count] : digitCounter) std::cout << digit << " --> " << count << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```